# How do you copy a Lua table by value?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Recently I wrote a bit of Lua code something like:

```
local a = {}
for i = 1, n do
   local copy = a
   -- alter the values in the copy
end
```

Obviously, that wasn't what I wanted to do since variables hold references to an anonymous table not the values of the table themselves in Lua.  This is clearly laid out in [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html), but I'd forgotten about it.

So the question is what should I write instead of `copy = a` to get a copy of the values in `a`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To play a little readable-code-golf, here's a short version that handles the standard tricky cases:

- tables as keys,
- preserving metatables, and
- recursive tables.

We can do this in 7 lines:

```
function copy(obj, seen)
  if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return obj end
  if seen and seen[obj] then return seen[obj] end
  local s = seen or {}
  local res = setmetatable({}, getmetatable(obj))
  s[obj] = res
  for k, v in pairs(obj) do res[copy(k, s)] = copy(v, s) end
  return res
end
```

There is a short write-up of Lua deep-copy operations in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/81333721109155b2d244).

Another useful reference is [this Lua-users wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable), which includes an example on how to avoid the `__pairs` metamethod.

Comment: Why are there two parameters if he's copying one object?

Comment: @claudekennilol The second parameter is meant to be ignored by the "outside" caller and only used for recursive calls. It avoids repeated deep copying of tables that occur more than once in a single table. E.g. a = {<any values>} b = {k1=a, k2=a}. If b2 is a copy of b, it's nice to keep b2.k1 == b2.k2. The extra `seen` parameter helps to make this possible.

Comment: This can go horribly wrong with metatables, especially since you're setting the metatable _first_ and then assigning the fields… (`__newindex` could do all sorts of funny things).  Further, `__pairs` or `__index` might be futzing with the iteration, so you'd better go `for k, v in next, obj, nil do` to copy the _actual contents_ (that's sort of the equivalent of `rawget` for `pairs`), before setting the metatable at the end (which will then make things look the same). Also: why not `seen = seen or {}` _as the first line_ (that's more readable) and then `if seen and seen[x]` --> `if seen[x]`?

Comment: @nobody: Short answer: this is short reasonable code that will work for many people finding this SO page.

If they want to deep copy a table with surprising-behavior assignment / iteration metamethods, I'd say they've voluntarily entered territory where they ought to know what they're doing. Your suggestion about putting the `seen` line first is good. I think I wrote it as it is because I wanted to keep the lines short (hence use `s` as a variable name) but also keep clear what that variable meant; giving it two names was my solution (so line count would be the same).

Comment: @Tyler haha as someone who've voluntarily entered that territory I'm still googling "how to copy a table lua." On a more serious note though, this kind of thing would be an issue for people using libraries that might use __newindex and __index for accessor-like syntax.

Answer (score 50):

Table copy has many potential definitions. It depends on whether you want simple or deep copy, whether you want to copy, share or ignore metatables, etc. There is no single implementation that could satisfy everybody.

One approach is to simply create a new table and duplicate all key/value pairs:

```
function table.shallow_copy(t)
  local t2 = {}
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    t2[k] = v
  end
  return t2
end

copy = table.shallow_copy(a)
```

Note that you should use `pairs` instead of `ipairs`, since `ipairs` only iterate over a subset of the table keys (ie. consecutive positive integer keys starting at one in increasing order).

Comment: This code is incorrect. I used it and it fails on one specific issue: what if you have tables inside tables. You need to check the type of v and use table.copy recursively when it's a table. I will post the code in a separate message below.

Comment: The code is not incorrect, it's a perfectly valid way to copy a table if you don't need recursive copy. If you need recursive copy, then make the function recursive. The very reason it's not included in standard libraries is that there is no single definition of "table copy".

Comment: I can see @scippie point. Perhaps what's needed is a name that better indicates the type of copying that's being done? I'll update the name to `shallow_copy`; let me know if there's any disagreements.

Comment: No, that is exactly my point. Good choice @greatwolf. I removed my downvote.

Comment: Do the key values have to be numeric?

Comment: No, pairs will iterate over all keys with non-nil values.

Answer (score 33):

Just to illustrate the point, my personal `table.copy` also pays attention to metatables:

```
function table.copy(t)
  local u = { }
  for k, v in pairs(t) do u[k] = v end
  return setmetatable(u, getmetatable(t))
end
```

There is no copy function sufficiently widely agreed upon to be called "standard".

Comment: Note that it is considered a bad practice to change or extend standard namespaces like `table`.

Comment: This works until someone sets the `__metatable` property of the metatable.

Comment: Also – as of Lua 5.2 – you should use the `next` function directly, as the behaviour of `pairs` may be affected by the metamethod `__pairs`. Also, you could solve the `__metatable` problem by using `debug.getmetatable`... but I'm not sure if that's OK to do.

Answer (score 24):

The full version of deep copy, handling all the 3 situations:

1. Table circular reference
2. Keys which are also tables
3. Metatable

The general version:

```
local function deepcopy(o, seen)
  seen = seen or {}
  if o == nil then return nil end
  if seen[o] then return seen[o] end

  local no
  if type(o) == 'table' then
    no = {}
    seen[o] = no

    for k, v in next, o, nil do
      no[deepcopy(k, seen)] = deepcopy(v, seen)
    end
    setmetatable(no, deepcopy(getmetatable(o), seen))
  else -- number, string, boolean, etc
    no = o
  end
  return no
end
```

Or the table version:

```
function table.deepcopy(o, seen)
  seen = seen or {}
  if o == nil then return nil end
  if seen[o] then return seen[o] end


  local no = {}
  seen[o] = no
  setmetatable(no, deepcopy(getmetatable(o), seen))

  for k, v in next, o, nil do
    k = (type(k) == 'table') and k:deepcopy(seen) or k
    v = (type(v) == 'table') and v:deepcopy(seen) or v
    no[k] = v
  end
  return no
end
```

Based on the [lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable)'s and [Alan Yates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710588/2294006)' functions.

Comment: Welcome to [SO] and thank you for the suggestions!  It looks like the `seen` variable is a sort of caching system.  I'll have to try it out.

Comment: This works well in my project and hope your feedback if there're pitfalls.

Comment: Hah, wish I'd scrolled down further before writing this myself! (IMO this should be the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 10):

An optionally deep, graph-general, recursive version:

```
function table.copy(t, deep, seen)
    seen = seen or {}
    if t == nil then return nil end
    if seen[t] then return seen[t] end

    local nt = {}
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if deep and type(v) == 'table' then
            nt[k] = table.copy(v, deep, seen)
        else
            nt[k] = v
        end
    end
    setmetatable(nt, table.copy(getmetatable(t), deep, seen))
    seen[t] = nt
    return nt
end
```

Perhaps metatable copy should be optional also?

Comment: You need to add `nt` to `seen` before iterating or there are circumstances where you'll overflow the stack. Basically, remove like 15 and insert it after line 6.

Comment: I was only thinking about "but what if t is its own metatable" but of course its also a problem if it's simply `local t={}; t[1] = t` or something. Also, after looking at http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable, I see you forgot to copy the keys, which can be tables themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I actually did:

```
for j,x in ipairs(a) do copy[j] = x end
```

As [Doub mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641993/1438), if your table keys are not strictly monotonically increasing, it should be `pairs` not `ipairs`.

I also found a [`deepcopy`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) function that is more robust:

```
function deepcopy(orig)
    local orig_type = type(orig)
    local copy
    if orig_type == 'table' then
        copy = {}
        for orig_key, orig_value in next, orig, nil do
            copy[deepcopy(orig_key)] = deepcopy(orig_value)
        end
        setmetatable(copy, deepcopy(getmetatable(orig)))
    else -- number, string, boolean, etc
        copy = orig
    end
    return copy
end
```

It handles tables and metatables by calling itself recursively ([which is its own reward](http://xkcd.com/1270)). One of the clever bits is that you can pass it any value (whether a table or not) and it will be copied correctly.  However, the cost is that it could potentially overflow the stack.  So and even more robust (non-recursive) [function](https://gist.github.com/Deco/3985043) might be needed.

But that's overkill for the very simple case of wanting to copy an array into another variable.

Comment: Note that this version of deepcopy does not work for self-referential (recursive) tables. (Which is what you get if you follow accepted practice for object oriented Lua.)

Comment: For the stack overflow problem, transforming the function to use tail calls would solve this. However, may not be possible.

Answer (score 4):

The (unfortunately lightly documented) [stdlib](http://luaforge.net/projects/stdlib) project has a number of valuable extensions to several of the libraries shipped with the standard Lua distribution. Among them are several variations on the theme of table copying and merging.

This library is also included in the [Lua for Windows](http://luaforwindows.luaforge.net/) distribution, and should probably be a part of any serious Lua user's toolbox.

One thing to make sure of when implementing things like this by hand is the proper handling of metatables. For simple table-as-structure applications you probably don't have any metatables, and a simple loop using `pairs()` is an acceptable answer. But if the table is used as a tree, or contains circular references, or has metatables, then things get more complex.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that functions are also references, so if you wanted to completely 'copy' all of the values you'd need to get separate functions, too; however, the only way I know to copy a function is to use `loadstring(string.dump(func))`, which according to the Lua reference manual, doesn't work for functions with upvalues.

```
do
    local function table_copy (tbl)
        local new_tbl = {}
        for key,value in pairs(tbl) do
            local value_type = type(value)
            local new_value
            if value_type == "function" then
                new_value = loadstring(string.dump(value))
                -- Problems may occur if the function has upvalues.
            elseif value_type == "table" then
                new_value = table_copy(value)
            else
                new_value = value
            end
            new_tbl[key] = new_value
        end
        return new_tbl
    end
    table.copy = table_copy
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason why Lua doesn't have 'table.copy()' in its standard libraries is because the task is not precise to define. As shown already here, one can either make a copy "one level deep" (which you did), a deepcopy with or without caring of possible duplicate references. And then there's metatables.

Personally, I would still like them to offer a built-in function. Only if people wouldn't be pleased with its semantics, they would need to go do it themselves. Not very often, though, one actually has the copy-by-value need.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: the marked solution is **INCORRECT**!

When the table contains tables, references to those tables will still be used instead. I have been searching two hours for a mistake that I was making, while it was because of using the above code.

So you need to check if the value is a table or not. If it is, you should call table.copy recursively!

This is the correct table.copy function:

```
function table.copy(t)
  local t2 = {};
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if type(v) == "table" then
        t2[k] = table.copy(v);
    else
        t2[k] = v;
    end
  end
  return t2;
end
```

Note: This might also be incomplete when the table contains functions or other special types, but that is possible something most of us don't need. The above code is easily adaptable for those who need it.

Comment: I think it's a little harsh to say that it's "incorrect".  It depends on what you have inside the table and what you want to copy.  You'll notice that several other answers _also_ account for recursive copying of tables.  Others account for metatables and functions.

Comment: IMO. the OP doesn't say anything about the contents of the table. Hence, the answer should be as complete as possible, which is not the case with the selected answer. Others like me will search for this question and will take the selected answer, searching for an error in their own code while it's not in theirs.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I am the OP and I had not considered the situation of recursively copying a table containing tables.  Several of the other answers covered that concern quite well.

Answer (score 1):

That's as good as you'll get for basic tables. Use something like deepcopy if you need to copy tables with metatables.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases when I needed to copy a table, I wanted to have a copy that doesn't share anything with the original, such that any modification of the original table has no impact on the copy (and vice versa).

All the snippets that have been shown so far fail at creating a copy for a table that may have shared keys or keys with tables as those are going to be left pointing to the original table. It's easy to see if you try to copy a table created as: `a = {}; a[a] = a`. [deepcopy](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) function referenced by Jon takes care of that, so if you need to create a real/full copy, `deepcopy` should be used.

Comment: How deep should `deepcopy` go?  Should `deepcopy({m = _G.mymodule})` copy whole `mymodule` table recursively or should it copy only reference to `mymodule` once it realized that `mymodule` is accessible from global env?

Answer (score 1):

Use penlight library here:
https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.tablex.html#deepcopy

```
local pl = require 'pl.import_into'()
local newTable = pl.tablex.deepcopy(oldTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the

```
local unpack = unpack or table.unpack

list2 = {unpack (list)}
```

Comment: note that this will fail if the list has more than 8000 items

Answer (score 0):

This might be the simplest method:

```
local data = {DIN1 = "Input(z)", DIN2 = "Input(y)", AINA1 = "Input(x)"}

function table.copy(mytable)  --mytable = the table you need to copy

    newtable = {}

    for k,v in pairs(mytable) do
        newtable[k] = v
    end
    return newtable
end

new_table = table.copy(data)  --copys the table "data"
```

Answer (score -3):

In my situation, when the information in the table is only data and other tables (excluding functions, ...), is the following line of code the winning solution:

```
local copyOfTable = json.decode( json.encode( sourceTable ) )
```

I'm writing Lua code for some home automation on a Fibaro Home Center 2. The implementation of Lua is very limited with no central library of functions you can refer to. Every function needs to be declared in the code so to keep the code serviceable, so one line solutions like this are favorable.