# Specify whever a lua parameter should be a copy or a reference

Tags: function, reference, lua

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify if the parameters of a lua function should be copied or just referenced. Color is an object representing a color.

For example, with this code

```
function editColor(col)
    col.r = 0
    print(tostring(col.r))
end

color = Color(255, 0, 0)
print(tostring(color.r))
editColor(color)
print(tostring(color.r))
```

Makes the output

```
255
0
0
```

So col is a "reference" to color, but this code:

```
function editColor(col)
    col = Color(0, 0, 0)
    print(tostring(col.r))
end

color = Color(255, 0, 0)
print(tostring(color.r))
editColor(color)
print(tostring(color.r))
```

Makes this output

```
255
0
255
```

So here the color is copied.

Is there a way to force a parameter to be copied or referenced? Just like the `&` operator in C++?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640642/how-do-you-copy-a-lua-table-by-value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, parameters in Lua are always passed [by value](http://wiki.vodpod.com/w/page/12352674/A%C2%A0Short-Lua-Tutorial) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20110811101759/http://wiki.vodpod.com/w/page/12352674/A%C2%A0Short-Lua-Tutorial)). All variables are *[references](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#2.2)* however. In your second example in editColor you're overriding what the variable col refers to, but it's only for that scope. You'll need to change things around, maybe instead of passing in a variable to be reassigned, have the function return something and do your reassignment outside. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.  Put the variable that you want to pass by reference into a table.  You can use a table to pass anything by ref, not just a string.

```
-- function that you want to pass the string  
-- to byref.  
local function next_level( w )  
  w.xml = w.xml .. '<next\>'  
end  


--  Some top level function that you want to use to accumulate text
function top_level()  
      local w = {xml = '<top>'} -- This creates a table with one entry called "xml".  
                            -- You can call the entry whatever you'd like, just be  
                            -- consistant in the other functions.  
  next_level(w)  

  w.xml = w.xml .. '</top>'  
  return w.xml  
end  

--output: <top><next\></top>
```