# Is there a way you can split a Lua table like you can a Python list obj

Tags: list, lua, lua-table

I'm building a lib and I need need to split a string, the string is like this

```
'PROTOCAL:ROOM:USER:MESSAGE:MESSAGE_ID:TIME_FLOAT'
```

In python I could just convert it into a list and then split the list, for example

```python
string = 'PROTOCAL:ROOM:USER:MESSAGE:MESSAGE_ID:TIME_FLOAT'
string = string.split(':', 1)
strlst = list()
for stri in string: strlst.append(stri)
```

Now with the list I could splice it like so,

```python
a = strlst[:0]
b = strlst[0:]
c = strlst[0]
```

Can this be done in Lua.

Comment: What would be the end results in `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: with the c variable I can get the first element in the list. With the b variable  I can get everything but the first element and so on.

Comment: `split` already gives you a list. Making another list and appending all the items from one to the other is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, `strlst[:0]` is an empty list, and `strlst[0:]` is a copy of the whole `strlst`. You might want to review how `split` and list slicing work, because you're doing much more work than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following split function would fail for a separator of length two or more. So, you wouldn't be able to use it with something like `,:` as a separator.

```
function split( sInput, sSeparator )
    local tReturn = {}
    for w in sInput:gmatch( "[^"..sSeparator.."]+" ) do
        table.insert( tReturn, w )
    end
    return tReturn
end
```

You'll use it as follows:

```
str = 'PROTOCAL:ROOM:USER:MESSAGE:MESSAGE_ID:TIME_FLOAT'
strlist = split( str, ':' )
```

Now, for lua-tables, the indexing starts at `1` and not `0`, and you can use `table.unpack` to slice small tables. So, you'll have:

```lua
a1 = {table.unpack(strlist, 1, 0)} -- empty table
a2 = {table.unpack(strlist, 1, 1)} -- just the first element wrapped in a table
b1 = {table.unpack(strlist, 1, #list)} -- copy of the whole table
b2 = {table.unpack(strlist, 2, #list)} -- everything except first element
c = strlist[1]
```

(`table.unpack` works in Lua 5.2, it is just `unpack` in Lua 5.1)

For larger tables you may need to write your own [shallow table copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641993/1190388) function.

Answer (score 0):

A version which supports separators of any length:

```
local function split(s, sep)
    local parts, off = {}, 1
    local first, last = string.find(s, sep, off, true)
    while first do
        table.insert(parts, string.sub(s, off, first - 1))
        off = last + 1
        first, last = string.find(s, sep, off, true)
    end
    table.insert(parts, string.sub(s, off))
    return parts
end
```