# Why I can't make separated table copies?

Tags: class, inheritance, lua, lua-table

In a file I do a code like this:

```
Source = {}
Source[1] = { a = 1, b = 2, ... }
```

in another file, I do the next:

```
Table = {}
Table[1] = Source[1]
Table[2] = Source[1]
```

I use this method for creating objects in Lua. Though, they don't act separately, for example, I can't give a different `a` value for the two tables.

Why? Also, what can I do for it? I want to avoid defining tables one by one.

Comment: `Source[2]` is `nil` from your code, are you trying to make `Table[2]` the same content as `Table[1]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you copy a Lua table by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640642/how-do-you-copy-a-lua-table-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the variables `Table[1]` and `Table[2]` are only references to the same table value, they don't contain the value.

To copy a table by value, copy the values one by one:

```
for k, v in pairs(Source[1]) do
    Table[1][k]  = v
    Table[2][k]  = v
end
```

For more on copying tables, see [How do you copy a Lua table by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640642/how-do-you-copy-a-lua-table-by-value).

Comment: Using `pairs` and `iparis` was always hard for me, because I've never leartn something like them in C++. Thank you!

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt It's pretty much the same `for (pair<string, int> c : map<string, int>({ { "a", 1 }, {"b", 2}} )) cout << c.first << "  " << c.second << endl;` except that Lua's [generic for statement](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5) allows multiple loop variables.

Comment: After several failed attempts of implementing this code, I realised that on the right side, a simple `v` is enough.