# Lua equals function and tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

My code is:

```
a = {"a1","a2","a3"}
b = a
b[1] = "b1"
print(a[1])
```

I can't understand why the result is "b1" instead of "a1".

The same is:

```
 a = {"a1","a2","a3"}
b = a
c = b
b[1] = "b1"
c[2] = "c2"
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[3])
```

The result will be: 
"b1" 
"c2"
"a3".

Can I copy variables in another way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640642/how-do-you-copy-a-lua-table-by-value

Comment: The assignment "b=a" is not a copy - like for instance in c++ a vector copy. Instead the assignment reads "let b point to the same table as a".