# New values in tables - shared?

Tags: lua

**Issue**

While trying to learn `lua` I accidentally found out that if

```
a = {"a"}
b = a
```

than this produces (no surprise):

```
a
{"a"} --[[table: 0x046bde18]]
b
{"a"} --[[table: 0x046bde18]]
```

but then if:

```
a[2] = "b"
```

why is `a == b` still `true`?

```
a
{"a", "b"} --[[table: 0x046bde18]]
b -- this is a surprise
{"a", "b"} --[[table: 0x046bde18]]
```

This seem to work both ways: if a new value is assigned to `b` then it will be also assigned to `a`.

On the other hand if I assign `a` a value (example: `a = 1`) and `b = a` then if `a` value is changed (`a = 2`) then `b` retains the original value (still `b = 1`).

**Questions**

1. Why is this behaviour different depending on wheather `a` is an array/table or a value? Is it due to built-in metatables (`__newindex`)?
2. What is the purpose of such behaviour of arrays/tables?
3. What if I wanted/needed to somehow seperate `a` and `b` (or what to do if I wanted to store the values of `a` before changing `b`)?

(I read Lua [Assignment](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.3) and [Metatables and Metamethods](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) chapters of the Lua Reference Manual but still have no clue why such behaviour occures.)

Comment: Why is this such a common problem. All you're doing is assigning variable b to the value a is assigned, b just points to the same thing a points to.

Comment: @warspyking as a novice programmer I find it counter intuitive (but justifiable as explained in the answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `a` and `b` are just references to the same table. In Lua, tables are objects, and you created a table and assigned it to `a` with the first statement, and then you created a second reference to the same table with the second assignment. So, both `a[2] = "b"` and `b[2] = "b"` are acting on the same underlying table (table: 0x046bde18).

A table is not a value, it is an object. `a = {"a"}` constructs a table and assigns a reference to the table to `a`. `b = a` assigns the same reference to `b`. But, `x = 10` assigns the value `10` to `x`. If `y = 10` and you could change the underlying value of `10`, I suppose that this change would be reflected in both `x` and `y`, but I know of no obvious way to do this. In this code:

```
x = 10
y = 10
y = y + 1
```

the resulting values will be `x = 10`, and `y = 11`. The underlying value of `10` has not changed, but `y` was reassigned to the value `11`.

If you want to work with two copies of the table that can change independently, you would need to write a function that copies the members of `a` into `b = {}`. [Here is a question that discusses making copies of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640642/how-do-you-copy-a-lua-table-by-value).