# Why does changing the value of a variable by a function change the value of the variable of it's parent table in Lua?

Tags: lua

```
Assertion = {
    key
}

print(Assertion.key)

function Assertion:brl(ky)
    self.key = ky
end

v = Assertion
v:brl(5)

print(Assertion.key)
print(v.key)
```

**Output**

```
nil
5
5
```

So my question is even though I have changed only 'v.key' why has 'Assertion.key' also changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v = Assertion
```

after this line `v` refers to `Assertion`. `Assertion = {}` wil create a new table and store a reference to that table in the variable `Assertion`. `Assertion` does not contain that table. `v =` Assertion` will just create a second reference to that table. It will not copy the table nor any of its contents.

So `v:brl(5)` is equivalent to `Assertion:brl(5)`. `v.key` is the very same value as `Assertion.v`

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual 2.1 Values and Types](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.1):

> Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects:
> variables do not actually contain these values, only references to
> them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always
> manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply
> any kind of copy.

If you want to make an actual copy of a table value read this

[How do you copy a Lua table by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640642/how-do-you-copy-a-lua-table-by-value)

If you're interested in OOP you might want to give this a read

https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming

Just in case you want mutliple objects share the same functions

Comment: Can you also please tell me how do I make 'v' a new object like Assertion in itself? Thank you!